# Make a model class and controller with two foreign id keys in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As am trying to learn .net core i started working on this basic project with a very simple idea, of having two tables called projects and consultants and a many to many relation ship between the two table which will result in having a third table called assign which will have both the the id of the project table and the consultant table.

I have managed to create a full working back end for the two tables project, and consultant ( you can see the models and controllers bellow ) but i have no idea how to represent the many to many relationship in order to create the class and controller for the assign table and the also the crud operations.

Please take a look at the classes and controllers bellow for the project and consultant table :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI_C5.Models
{
    public class Consultant
    {
        public int ConsultantId { get; set; }
        public string ConsultantName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI_C5.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ConsultantController.cs :

```
namespace WebAPI_C5.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ConsultantController : ControllerBase
    {
        // to access the configuration from the app.settings file 
        // we need to make use of the dependency injection 
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public ConsultantController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        // API method to get project details 
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            string query = @" select ConsultantId,ConsultantName from dbo.Consultant";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader);
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(table);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post(Consultant cons)
        {
            string query = @"
                    insert into dbo.Consultant values 
                    ('" + cons.ConsultantName + @"')
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Added Successfully");
        }
        // to update data 
        [HttpPut]
        public JsonResult Put(Consultant cons)
        {
            string query = @"
                    update dbo.Consultant set 
                    ConsultantName = '" + cons.ConsultantName + @"'
                    where ConsultantId = " + cons.ConsultantId + @" 
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Updated Successfully");
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public JsonResult Delete(int id)
        {
            string query = @"
                    delete from dbo.Consultant
                    where ConsultantId = " + id + @" 
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;
                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Deleted Successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[If you operate like post and tag models in Microsoft docs page and declare 2 navigation properties like the following line, EF will create a new table with 2 Foreign keys pointing to those tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

EF will create in a relational database for the above model.

```
CREATE TABLE [Posts] (
    [PostId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Title] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Posts] PRIMARY KEY ([PostId])
);

CREATE TABLE [Tags] (
    [TagId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tags] PRIMARY KEY ([TagId])
);

CREATE TABLE [PostTag] (
    [PostsId] int NOT NULL,
    [TagsId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostTag] PRIMARY KEY ([PostsId], [TagsId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Posts_PostsId] FOREIGN KEY ([PostsId]) REFERENCES [Posts] ([PostId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Tags_TagsId] FOREIGN KEY ([TagsId]) REFERENCES [Tags] ([TagId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Am not really sure this answers my question but thank you for the help !

Comment: You do not need create a new model class , you can define navigation properties like Posts and Tags.

Comment: thank you for editing your answer, so just adding the iCollection in both classes will generate a new table with both foreign keys, how would i go about the controller do i need to make one for the new generated table ?

Comment: I do not think it is needed to make a new controller

Comment: how will i be able to make basic crud operations on the new generated table from the many to many relation ship ?

Comment: EF will handle its CRUD operations behind the scenes